# PyOpenNI Depth Generator refresh

Tags: python, numpy, openni

I am capturing depth images from the Asus Xtion Live Pro using [PyOpenNI](https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI). Here's a short example of code:

```
from openni import *
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

context = Context()
context.init()

depth = DepthGenerator()
depth.create(context)
depth.set_resolution_preset(RES_VGA)
depth.fps = 30
context.start_generating_all()
context.wait_any_update_all()
frame = np.fromstring(depth.get_raw_depth_map_8(), "uint8").reshape(480, 640)
cv2.imwrite("image.png", frame)
```

This works fine, but if I want to get a stream flow of depth images with a loop every second,

```
while True:
   frame = np.fromstring(depth.get_raw_depth_map_8(), "uint8").reshape(480, 640)
   cv2.imwrite("image.png", frame)
   time.sleep(1)
```

the images are all the same, even though I am moving in front of the sensor. It seems that the Xtion does not refresh the acquisition of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
You have to call:

```
context.wait_any_update_all()
context.wait_and_update_all()
context.wait_one_update_all(Generator)
```